# Why HoughCircles is detecting false circles?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to find circles in a live video feed from my laptop's default camera using **Hough Circle Detection** in **OpenCV** with **Python**, but it detects hundreds of circles in the video.

Here's my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)

    detected_circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

    for (x, y, r) in detected_circles[0, :]:
        cv2.circle(gray, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 255), 2)

    cv2.imshow('Live', gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've also tried it by playing video from a file, but it didn't worked.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)`

Try changing `minRadius` parameter to a larger value like 5 or more.

Here is the code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.medianBlur(frame, 5)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=10, maxRadius=20)
    if circles is not None:
        detected_circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        for (x, y, r) in detected_circles[0, :]:
            cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 255), 2)

    cv2.imshow('Live', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```